# Not able to install bundle

Tags: ruby, rspec, selenium-webdriver, capybara, bundle

I am new to development of Capybara with Rspec using Ruby with selenium. I have installed Caybara and installed RSpec also. But when I am trying to install it is giving an error "Couldn't locate Gemfile". How to rectify the error? How to locate the Gemfile. Is there any Tutorial for Capybara and Rspec to understand better about those?

I am installing those on Windows8.1Pro

Comment: Please be clear about what you're doing when you're "trying to install". Perhaps you're doing `bundle install`? If you're not using Rails (which generates a Gemfile) you'll need to write your own; see the bundler documentation.

Comment: Thank you Dave for your answer. I could able to solve the problem by adding the Gemfile to the root path